# Running RabbitMQ in a Windows Server

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a question about how to correctly set RabbitMQ Broker in a Windows Server.
I manage to install it as Windows Service by running *rabbitmq-service.bat install*, but if I try to connect an application it complains that it can't find a broker.

If I manually start *rabbitmq-server.bat* as a console everything works.

But how do I manage to make it work on a server without that manual step?
Should the application itself start/stop the broker?